# Sync XAMPP Localhost database with Android database onClick

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, xampp

So I have a MySQL database on a localhost web server and a SQLite database on an Android app. I have a "Sync" button on the Android app, which should update the Android database based on the localhost database, when I click the "Sync" button. I have a php file which outputs the localhost database in JSON format. Right now, my Android "Sync" button parses the JSON from that php file and then Inserts the data into the database. How do I implement it to update the Android database when the Localhost database rows have been updated or deleted?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the model below

[image]

Comment: Hi @quangminhs, thanks for the answer. However, what if I delete a row in MySQL DB, there would no row to send as JSON.